# Google Appscript code to auto create, attach, and send a pdf created from a Google Form through email not working?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, email-attachments

I am trying to create an automated report for my Team.  I have a very basic understanding of coding but not enough to really troubleshoot or add my own code when something goes wrong or doesn't work.  I appreciate any help in advance.

When my Team fills out the form there is a drop down question for the email where they will choose which location to email the PDF to, so that it can be printed out and signed.  It is this email in column C that I need the script to identify and use to send the email and attached PDF.

I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpZGvKIHmR8) and followed it step by step, except for one section where he collects emails and sets up pdf links within the spreadsheet (under the "Adding a Link to the PDF" section of his video).

I have setup exactly as he has.  This code works up until the email and attachment part, as in it takes the information from the Sheet, creates a temporary file using the Doc Template, creates a PDF from the temp file, saves the PDF in the correct folder, and then deletes the temp file.  But even when the execution log says it completes, no email is ever sent.

My apologies if this is too lengthy, I was trying to be thorough.

I have tried rewatching that video multiple times to ensure that I followed the instructions step by step and my code matched his.  I attempted to Google a solution and watch other videos, but my skill level is limited to copying code and making slight changes, not troubleshooting or introducing new code.

**Here is the code I have so far:
**

```
function afterFormSubmit(e) {
  const info = e.namedValues;
  const pdfFile = createPDF(info);
  
  sendEmail(e.namedValues['email'][0],pdfFile);   

}


function sendEmail(email, pdfFile){
 
  GmailApp.sendEmail('email', "Subj", "Body", {
  attachments: [pdfFile], 
  name: 'My Company'
});

}

// everything from here below works, use {} and '' instead of {{}} and "", use [0] instead of [1][2]etc.

function createPDF(info){

const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1YPB0_lw2QPw5bMrmrlw3_kcIchRGQmYG");
const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1Um5h762rBmI-j_J8arTCmMoOEvEyKdIX");
const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("1kN5DJqi04cY638B-0yKZYg-JHaLmt1jvv6kH25PjIgc");

const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);

const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
const body = openDoc.getBody();
body.replaceText("{timestamp}", info['Timestamp'][0]);
body.replaceText("{name}", info['name'][0]);
body.replaceText("{email}", info['email'][0]);
body.replaceText("{body}", info['body'][0]);
openDoc.saveAndClose();

const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info['name'][0] + " " + new Date());
tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);

}
```

**Current Trigger set up:
**
Deployment: Head
Event: From spreadsheet = On form submit
Function: afterFormSubmit

**Error for the above code the Execution log gives me:
**
Exception: Invalid argument: attachments

```
at sendEmail(Code:12:12)
at afterFormSubmit(Code:5:3)
```

[Here is the code above in appscript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKe1N.png)
[Trigger set up from appscript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h49gp.png)
[This is the Sheet and the information it collected, emails are in Column C.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLFBq.png)
[Here is the Google Doc Template I created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whnar.png)
[Here is the PDF created from the temporary file using the Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2Xtc.png)

Answer (score 1):

#### Modification points:

- In your showing script, at `GmailApp.sendEmail('email', "Subj", "Body", {`, `email` is not used as the variable. By this, an error occurs. I guess that this might be the reason for your current issue of `**Error for the above code the Execution log gives me: ** Exception: Invalid argument: attachments`.
- And, in your script, `pdfFile` of `const pdfFile = createPDF(info);` is undefined. Because the function `createPDF` returns no value.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function afterFormSubmit(e) {
  const info = e.namedValues;
  const pdfFile = createPDF(info);
  sendEmail(info['email'][0], pdfFile);
}

function sendEmail(email, pdfFile) {
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "Subj", "Body", {
    attachments: [pdfFile],
    name: 'My Company'
  });
}

function createPDF(info) {
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1YPB0_lw2QPw5bMrmrlw3_kcIchRGQmYG");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1Um5h762rBmI-j_J8arTCmMoOEvEyKdIX");
  const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("1kN5DJqi04cY638B-0yKZYg-JHaLmt1jvv6kH25PjIgc");

  const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  const body = openDoc.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{timestamp}", info['Timestamp'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{name}", info['name'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{email}", info['email'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{body}", info['body'][0]);
  openDoc.saveAndClose();
  const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info['name'][0] + " " + new Date());
  newTempFile.setTrashed(true);
  return pdfFile;
}
```

- In this modified script, when Google Form is submitted, the function `afterFormSubmit` is run and creates a PDF file, and an email is sent with an attachment file of a PDF file.
- In this case, it supposes that this function is included in the container-bound script of Google Spreadsheet linking with Google Form. And, the function `afterFormSubmit` has already been installed as the OnSubmit trigger. Please be careful about this.

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, I do not know your actual Google Form and situation. So, I proposed only the modification points of your showing script.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I think I understand part of what I did wrong in not tabbing over the lines of code to be under each respective function.  I copied over your modified code and now get the error "ReferenceError: email is not defined at afterFormSubmit (Code: 4:27)"  I did provide screen shots of everything that happens once a Google Form is submitted, would you need to see a screenshot of the actual Form itself?  Thank you again for your help, I am pretty new at this.

Comment: Nevermind!  I got it to work!  Thank you so much for your help.  The only other change I had to make was under the afterFormSubmit function I need to change sendEmail(e.namedValues['email'][0], pdfFile); to sendEmail(info['email'][0], pdfFile);

Comment: @Justin Holt Thank you for replying. About `sendEmail(info['email'][0], pdfFile);`, I modified the above modified script. Thank you, too. And, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your all issues were resolved from this situation. If your all issues were not still resolved, I have to apologize. Can I ask you about whether your all issues were resolved?

Comment: @JustinHolt If this answer met your needs, then you might consider "accepting" it - you can find details here: [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)